# Incorrect displaying of menu items text in status bar - wxWidgets 3.0

Tags: c++, menu, wxwidgets, windows-7-x64, statusbar

I am writing simple GUI software using wxWidgets 3.0 in CodeBlocks 13.12, on Win 7 x64 machine.

I would like to create a menu for the frame, and each item in the frame should make a different text appear in the status bar when highlighted. Below is what I have done so far ( only the menu part of code ). Menu and status bar appear as planned. The problem is that every item ( in File and Data sub menus ) when highlighted displays "Save project" in the status bar - which is the very first item in the first sub menu. How to change this so that proper menu item names are displayed ?

**CODE :**

```
    wxMenuBar* mbar = new wxMenuBar();

    wxMenu* fileMenu = new wxMenu(_T(""));
    //fileMenu->Append(, _("&"), _("")));
    fileMenu->Append(SaveProject, _("&Save project"), _("Save project"));
    fileMenu->Append(SaveProjectAs, _("&Save project as"), _("Save project as"));
    fileMenu->Append(OpenNewProject, _("&Open new project"), _("Open new project"));
    fileMenu->Append(OpenExistingProject, _("&Open existing project"), _("Open existing project"));
    fileMenu->AppendSeparator();
    fileMenu->Append(Quit, _("&Quit"), _("Quit"));

    mbar->Append(fileMenu, _("&File"));

    wxMenu* dataMenu = new wxMenu(_T(""));
    //fileMenu->Append(, _("&"), _("")));
    dataMenu->Append(ImportData, _("&Import data"), _("Import data"));
    dataMenu->Append(ExportData, _("&Export data"), _("Export data"));
    dataMenu->Append(SavaDataAs, _("&Save data as"), _("Save data as"));

    mbar->Append(dataMenu, _("&Data"));

    mainFrame->SetMenuBar(mbar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is due to your use of duplicate menu IDs (e.g. `SaveProject` is used twice). While it's not clear why should this result in the observed behaviour, it is pretty clear that you cannot reuse the menu IDs as you will have no way of distinguishing between the events generated by the two items with the same ID. So don't do this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The thing you pointed out using same menu ID twice, was a typo in my question and I edited it. I solved the problem using different way of enumerating menu IDs. At first I did it with help of wxID_HIGHEST + 1, but it didn't work, and I don't really know why.

Comment: This seems very suspicious, creating menu items is something done by almost any wxWidgets program and I'd be very surprised if such a problem could go unnoticed for so long. My second hypothesis is that you're doing something else in your program that you don't show us because, as written, and after ensuring that all IDs are unique, this code should definitely work.